# In TCL Script generate specific data structure in the file

Tags: tcl

I am trying to generate this structure
eg:

```
type (bus0) {
      base_type : array ;
      data_type : bit ;
      bit_width :  2;
      bit_from :  1;
      bit_to :  0;
      downto : true ;
    }
bus (BITS_CLK2QDLY) {
  bus_type : bus0
```

In **type (bus0) {** where bus increment each time, bit_width, bit_from and bit_to values will updated from dictionary, where `bit_width = bit_to + 1`.
**BITS_CLK2QDLY** dictionary name.

In the code that I tried, here I completed till `$keyword_numbers` only I have doubts in the last section of the first two blocks to know the code

```
proc fileinput {filename} {
    set filedata [open $filename "r"]
    set file [read $filedata]
        ............
        ...........
    return $data
}

set data [fileinput "rx_clkgen_tdl_ss_0.675v_m40c.lib"]
```

where the `$data` consist

```
pin ("BITS_CLK2QDLY[0]")
pin ("BITS_CLK2QDLY[1]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[0]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[1]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[2]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[3]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[4]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[5]")
pin ("BITS_DCC_MAIN[6]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[0]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[1]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[2]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[3]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[4]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[5]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[6]")
pin ("BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN[7]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[0]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[1]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[2]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[3]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[4]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[5]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[6]")
pin ("BITS_NDE_DLY[7]")
```

```
foreach item $data {
    if {[regexp {(\w+)\[(\d+)\]} $item -> keyword number]} {
        if [dict exists $keyword_numbers $keyword] {
            dict set keyword_numbers $keyword bit_start [expr {min([dict get $keyword_numbers $keyword bit_start], $number)}]
            dict set keyword_numbers $keyword bit_end   [expr {max([dict get $keyword_numbers $keyword bit_end], $number)}]
        } else {
            dict set keyword_numbers $keyword [dict create bit_start $number bit_end $number]
        }
    }
}
```

where the data in `$keyword_numbers` is

```
BITS_CLK2QDLY {bit_start 0 bit_end 1} BITS_DCC_MAIN {bit_start 0 bit_end 6} BITS_FIXDLY_MAIN {bit_start 0 bit_end 7} BITS_NDE_DLY {bit_start 0 bit_end 7}
```

in the below code, I am unable to create/generate the above-mentioned format

```
set bus_counter -1

proc add_bus_type {base_type data_type bit_width bit_from bit_to downto} {

    foreach {bus_name {bit_start bit_end}} [dict sort $keyword_numbers] {
        set bus [incr bus_counter]
        set bus_type "bus$bus_counter"
        set bit_width [expr $bit_end - $bit_start + 1]
        set bit_to $bit_start
        set bit_from $bit_end
        add_bus_type $bus_type "array" $bit_width $bit_from $bit_to "true"
    }
}
```

Please analyze the above code and let me know the update or any changes.

any doubts/ clarification Please add comments

Comment: Are you trying to generate text or binary data?

Comment: @DonalFellows i am trying to generate text

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you don't want to call add_bus_type recursively - just generate the "structure" as "text". Then you could start with this:

```
proc add_bus_type {keyword_numbers} {
    set bus_counter -1
    foreach bus_name [lsort [dict keys $keyword_numbers]] {
        set base_type "array"
        set data_type "bit"
        set bit_start [dict get $keyword_numbers $bus_name bit_start]
        set bit_end [dict get $keyword_numbers $bus_name bit_end]
        set bus [incr bus_counter]
        set bus_type "bus$bus_counter"
        set bit_width [expr $bit_end - $bit_start + 1]
        set bit_to $bit_start
        set bit_from $bit_end
        set downto "true"
        puts [format "type (%s) \{" $bus_type]
        foreach i {base_type data_type bit_width bit_from bit_to downto} {
            puts [format "\t$i : %s \;" [set $i]]
        }
        puts "\}"
        puts [format "bus (%s) \{" $bus_name]
        puts [format "\tbus_type : %s ;\n\}" $bus_type]
        #puts [list $bus_type "array" $bit_width $bit_from $bit_to "true"]
    }
}
```

calling `add_bus_type $keyword_numbers`

gives the following output

```
type (bus0) {
    base_type : array ;
    data_type : bit ;
    bit_width : 2 ;
    bit_from : 1 ;
    bit_to : 0 ;
    downto : true ;
}
bus (BITS_CLK2QDLY) {
    bus_type : bus0 ;
}

. . .

type (bus3) {
    base_type : array ;
    data_type : bit ;
    bit_width : 8 ;
    bit_from : 7 ;
    bit_to : 0 ;
    downto : true ;
}
bus (BITS_NDE_DLY) {
    bus_type : bus3 ;
}
```